# PHP Display Error on submission

Tags: php, html

So I made a registration form such that the user **must** select one of the three radio options before continuing. However if the user didn't choose an option and clicked submit I want to display at least a message that says "please choose an option" or something. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$reg_type = "";
function setclick()
{
    if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
        $clicked=1;
    else 
        $clicked=0;
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["Reg_type"])) {
        $clicked=1;
        header('Location: Registration_1.php');
    }
    else {
        $reg_type = $_POST["Reg_type"];
        header('Location: Registration_2.php');
    }
}
echo $clicked;
?>

<form name="frmtype" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" >
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="1"/> Registering myself with credit card or bank account <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="2"/> Registering multiple people using credit card or bank account <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="3"/> Registering multiple people using a purchase order <br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
<?php 
setclick();
if($clicked)
    echo "Please select an option";
?>
```

I'm having a real hard time getting the logic down to display the error message if they didn't choose an option and clicked submit.

Comment: That can be done easily.  But, the easiest way is making the first radio button checked by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setclick()` function will always set `$clicked` to true if the form has been posted. Since you then call `setclick()` after your main php block, it will be true whether or not the  rest of the logic has changed it. Try this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['Reg_type']) && $_POST['Reg_type'] != ''){ 
    $reg_type = $_POST['Reg_type'];
    header('Location: Registration_2.php');
 } else $clicked = true;
```

and then down the bottom of the page under the form:

```
 if($clicked) echo "Please select an option";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    function checkform(){

    var checked = false;
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length ; i++) {
       if (buttons[i].checked) {
           checked = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   return checked;

   }
</script>

<form onsubmit="return checkform()">
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="1"/> Registering myself with credit card or bank account <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="2"/> Registering multiple people using credit card or bank account <br/>
<input type="radio" name="Reg_type" value="3"/> Registering multiple people using a purchase order <br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVDmF/)

This should get you started. Please be aware that this script is selecting elements by tag name, which means it will pick up any input in the form. If you are OK with using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) I'd highly recommend it, it will make this kind of tasks trivial.

Comment: We're talking PHP, not javascript. Old matey potatey's doing server side validation

Comment: Please do not validate anything on client side.

Comment: @FirmView this is merely to enhance the user experience, not for security. Validation should be done on the server side regardless.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $reg_type = $_POST['Reg_type'];

 if($reg_type == "1"){
       //action 1
 } else if($reg_type == "2"){
      //action 2 
 } else if($reg_type == "3") {
     //action 3 
 } else {
    // no radio button is checked. display the message

    $message = "Please select an option";
 }

?>
```